# Menu doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I try to display a menu but I can't! I didn't find the problem in my code!
Can anyone help me please?

This is the css file!  I think the problem came from the list position!

```css
.user-info .info-container .user-helper-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    bottom: -12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -50px;
    display: block !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   
<div class="info-box bg-pink hover-expand-effect" style="width: 285px; top:0%">
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="material-icons">input</i>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="text">Mes demandes</div>
        <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="nav-bar-name"></div>
        <div class="btn-group user-helper-dropdown">
            <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">input</i>Sign Out</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's in style.css ? does it contain any styling of the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are few thing-

First, you are not importing the required css file for the icons to work.

Second,  you are using pull-right for the dropdown which will make it go the right side that is out of screen acc to current code

Third, you have written  `display: block !important;` in the css which is making dropdown always appear, so we will remove that also.

Something like this

```css
.user-info .info-container .user-helper-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: -3px;
    bottom: -12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="info-box bg-pink hover-expand-effect" style="width: 285px; top:0%">
        <div class="icon">
            <i class="material-icons">input</i>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="text">Mes demandes</div>
            <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="nav-bar-name"></div>
            <div class="btn-group user-helper-dropdown">
                <i class="material-icons" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">person</i>Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="seperator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="material-icons">input</i>Sign Out</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```